# Find Element with Selenuim Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I started working with Selenium Java. I would like to indicate the search element for a website. Whatever Xpath, CssSelector...
The site is this **https://www.paruvendu.fr/** et i would like to create a car locator ad.
This is my code

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");

    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    Map<String, Integer> timeOUts = new HashMap<>();
    timeOUts.put("implicit", 1000);
    chromeOptions.setCapability("timeouts", timeOUts);

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    driver.get("https://www.paruvendu.fr/");
    js.executeScript("cmp_pv.cookie.saveConsent(false);");
    driver.navigate().refresh();
    driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Déposer une annonce gratuite")).click();     
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Choisissez une catégorie")).click();
```

I can access the form to drop off the car. And I can’t click on it to open it and select "Choose a category". And "MOTO-BATEAU" and finally "Used car"
Normally, at that point, it’s over.
Help me, I’m stuck and I thank you in advance.

i have this message Error

```
For documentation on this error, please visit: 
https://selenium.dev/exceptions/#no_such_element
Build info: version: '4.7.2', revision: '4d4020c3b7'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: 
'10.0', java.version: '11.0.16'
 Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
 Command: [7d5bbe84f8b9a235778639176345e277, findElement {using=link 
 text, value=Choisissez une catégorie}]
  Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, 
browserVersion: 109.0.5414.75, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 109.0.5414.74 
(e7c5703604da..., userDataDir: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\T...}, 
goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:54474}, 
networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: 
WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:54474/devtoo..., 
se:cdpVersion: 109.0.5414.75, setWindowRect: true, 
strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 1000, pageLoad: 
300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, 
webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
```

Comment: it is a bit difficult to understand what the problem is. Could you probably add a few screenshots and show what is working and what is not? Maybe then we find a solution.  From what I understand, you want to 1. click on the Choisissez une catégorie dropdown,  2. Select AUTO-MOTO-BATEAU, 3. Select Voiture d'occasion. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Code is with the two proposition. It's like this

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\kafka\\chromedriver.exe");

    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    Map<String, Integer> timeOUts = new HashMap<>();
    timeOUts.put("implicit", 1000);
    chromeOptions.setCapability("timeouts", timeOUts);

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    driver.get("https://www.paruvendu.fr/");
    js.executeScript("cmp_pv.cookie.saveConsent(false);");
    driver.navigate().refresh();
    driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Déposer une annonce gratuite")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-type=1]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(),'AUTO-MOTO-BATEAU')]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//li[normalize-space()=\"Voiture d'occasion\"])[1]")).click();
```

And I want to complete the steps to fill in the fields and publish the ad.
And Thank you #Shawn and #Prophet becouse this code is a mixture of two codes :)

Answer (score 1):

I could not understand what you mean by `and finally "Used car"`.
It's always recommended to wait for elements to be clickable before you trying to click them.
Also we almost never use `By.partialLinkText` and `By.linkText`. It's always better to use XPath, CSS Selector, ID or class name.
The following code opens the web page, closes the cookies banner, opens the drop list, opens "AUTO-MOTO-BATEU", then finally selects "Motos, Scooters et Quads" sub-category.
I mostly used Xpathes here since these elements could easily be located based on their texts.
This is my code:

```java
driver.get("https://www.paruvendu.fr/");
WebDriverUtils.clickVisible(driver,By.xpath("//button[contains(@onclick,'saveConsent(true)')]"));
WebDriverUtils.clickVisible(driver,By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Choisissez une catégorie')]"));
WebDriverUtils.clickVisible(driver,By.xpath("//li[contains(text(),'AUTO')]"));
WebDriverUtils.clickVisible(driver,By.xpath("//li[contains(text(),'Motos')]"));
```

The `clickVisible` method used here is implemented as following:

```java
public static boolean clickVisible(WebDriver driver, By locator) {
    try {
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator)).click();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ConsoleLogger.error("Failed to click on element " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding of your issue is correct, your below line of code is not working?

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Choisissez une catégorie")).click();
```

If yes, instead of using linkText locator, try using a relative xPath, try the below code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-type=1]")).click();
```